# Config Entity list_builder controller path throws Route Does Not Exist error

Tags: 8, entities, routes

I have created a custom config entity, which declares a list_builder controller to return a list of the created entities. Before creating a config entity, it renders as expected. Once I create a config entity via its add form, which redirects back to the list_builder controller, the error is thrown. The config entity is saved, but the redirect fails.

Here's the redirect in the config entity form class's ::save() method.

```
$form_state->setRedirect('my_module.entity.list');
```

Also, navigating directly to the list_builder controller path throws the same error.

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route
>   "entity.config_entity_id.edit_form" does not exist. in
>   Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRouteByName() (line 187 of
>   /home/vagrant/docroot/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php)

I have no idea where the route entity.config_entity_id.edit_form is coming from. How to resolve the thrown error?

Comment: Add the annotation of the entity class and your routing.yml file.

Answer (score 1):

You have somewhere in your code the wrong route.

Probably your route in *.routing.yml is:

```
entity.my_new_entity.edit_form
```

But now you are redirecting to

```
entity.config_entity_id.edit_form
```

where there is still the placeholder from some example code.

Comment: I added my form redirect in the question above. I'm redirecting to the list_builder route, which is why I can't determine how the route that does not exist is being passed on to Symfony's router. Additionally, if I navigate directly to the list_builder path, I get the same error.

Comment: grep for the string `config_entity_id`, if you find it replace it with the correct id of your new config entity

Comment: I think the route, entity.config_entity_id.edit_form, was generated dynamically from the schema definition. Changing the schema fixed the issue.

Comment: Please put this in an answer, and accept it, so also others can see the end result!